# thumbnail to large image jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, tooltip

In my view i am using this to show my images as thumbnails on each record

```
<img src="<?php echo Router::url("**../files/images/small/**".$ad["Advertisement"]["advertisement_image"],false)?>
```

with thumbnails saving in small directory folders, same large images are stored under big directory folder.

Can you please tell me how can I get large images of same thumbnail as I am using jQuery tooltip for large preview of images, how can I implement this in 
what should i give in alt for my above code.

```
<img src="hills-thumb.jpg" alt="hills.jpg" rel="Hills Image" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thumbnail img").hover(function(e) {
        $("#large").css("top", (e.pageY + 5) + "px")
            .css("left", e.pageX + 5) + "px")
        .html("<img src=" + $(this).attr("alt") + " alt='Large Image' /><br/>" + $(this).attr("rel"))
        .fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        $("#large").fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this that uses jquery tooltip for image preview.

http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

Comment: yeah  it works ... !! but i got my anwser for the above mentioned query

Comment: so you got your answer? i am not sure what you meant